# How can I type a prop of an object depending on another prop's type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Consider the next example:

```js
enum ActionTypes {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
}

type ActionProps = {
    [ActionTypes.A]: {
        a: string
    }
    [ActionTypes.B]: {
        b: string
    }
}

type Action = {
    [type in keyof ActionProps]: {
        type: type
    } & ActionProps[type]
}

//produces the expected result, but not ideal for the case

const state1: Action[ActionTypes] = {
    type: ActionTypes.A,
    a: 'string',
};

(() => {
    if (state1.type === ActionTypes.A) {
        state1.a = 'anotherstring';
        //doesn't error, because the compiler knows
        //the possible properties by state.type
    }
})();

//doesn't produce the expected result, but it would be ideal for the case

type State = {
    type: ActionTypes
    actionProps: ActionProps[State['type']]
}

const state2: State = {
    type: ActionTypes.A,
    actionProps: {
        a: 'string',
        b: 'string',
    }
};

(() => {
    if (state2.type === ActionTypes.A) {
        state2.actionProps.a = 'anotherstring';
        //errors - Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ b: string; }'
    }
})();
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=56&pc=6#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYBnKAbwFgAoKC2KAXigHIY6AaMyqAIRvvbrIF8yZBDmCxEqEAAUATimwFaJcpQDa8ZGiy48AOhgBdAFxFWbSgENjeBNKQgA5qYoDlFNeM0jd7IyddmAIysbO0d-FxchETENEC4lNhVhXCg7KABrYEwUADMYiRk5PF8Eswpk4GMKpyg%20KAAyfLRC%20SSRfX5BUgB6buxZABMwOHwoBAALUWAAD1xEYAGoaXwwABsEJigAsAQoEBRdpAHgc1WoHJRpMcmoOHM8YC64NGsoa3MEYABGY3UJd1iWnw%20niNQqvw8GC8ehY-ks9GstgczH4AG4ugAKDEAShoAD4-GwkHkMe9Pl8dBUaNRaH9PNo9LjSmUyd8dOYuHRzPsJsBpIjQnR0f42L0Bih8CA6Ls%20bJpJsAsA7mAHtdRM8INgkKs%20Rl9gB3PA1UXdXlQbAoPB4JABHXm2S4aTIUYBTBvBAfYCUkQ1CLYnHCshiiV4KW7fooIYjNVQGZzT6LZZ4NYbLY7VK7fUoNaLRWpY6nc6XGN3B5dKkAZQ9n1B-nBTSh2hq5khLTwENibZUVc9KmlIjo%20g6pEipGeIFerIATMYezXFGCRB2JEDdDBYWwW52He3CWUoPC6ALkRv90EESET760Zicfi9xRiVBSdXgFPvSkabTIavGQ%20zNO7Ktju7KctyByTPyl72EKxqUL0sqXAQAC0UAtHywj0OYdBQOKow8rG0xIK8aBjNEdCEFswRIvYqK1Lw4T8P62KokAA)

The expected result would be that if the compiler knows that `state.type === ActionTypes.A`, it knows that the type of `state.actionProps` is `ActionProps[ActionTypes.A]`.

Are there any possible workaround for that?

Comment: I don't understand "produces the expected result, but not ideal for the case".  Why is it not ideal?  You need a discriminated union if you want this sort of narrowing based on control flow, and `Action[keyof ActionProps]` is exactly the right type.  So what doesn't work for you there?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a generic:

```
enum ActionTypes {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
}

type ActionProps = {
    [ActionTypes.A]: {
        a: string
    }
    [ActionTypes.B]: {
        b: string
    }
}

type State<Type extends keyof ActionProps> = {
    type: Type
    actionProps: ActionProps[Type] & ActionProps[keyof ActionProps]
}

const state: State<ActionTypes.A> = {
    type: ActionTypes.A,
    actionProps: {
        a: 'string',
        b: 'string',
    }
};

(() => {
    if (state.type === ActionTypes.A) {
        state.actionProps.a = 'anotherstring';
        //errors - Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ b: string; }'
    }
})();
```

However, it seems TypeScript is not able to infer the type parameter based on the value of the `.type` property, that feature appears to be reserved for [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).